# using while loop with logical operators (AND and OR)

Tags: r

```
n<-NULL
acr<-NULL
while((is.numeric(n)==F) & (acr<0 ¦acr>1)){
   print("enter a  positive integer and the average cancellation rate you want")
   try(n<-scan(what=integer(),nmax=1), silent=TRUE);
   try(acr<-scan(what=double(),nmax=1), silent=TRUE)
}
```

I would want the users of my program to enter a positive integer which I store in "n" and the second 
entry which I keep in "acr" is a probability so it lies between 0 and 1.
(I don't want it to be exacly 0 or 1, though it could be according to probability theory).
So I want the user to keep on doing the entry until they are able to enter a positive integer for "n" and a probability value between 0 and 1 for "acr".(using while with the AND, OR operators)

However, I am having a problem with the while statement/loop. I have tried all other possibilities such as the one below, but it still doesn't work.

```
while(is.numeric(n)==F & acr<0 ¦acr>1)
```

AGAIN:question 2 
There is a problem with `what=double()` also in the `scan` function, I think.
I know that, for example, 0.5 is a double data type in other programming languages but 
I cannot figure it out in R(I don't know what it is called in R).
what is the difference between `integer()` and `double()` in R? (I am not familiar with double)

I would be highly appreciative to anyone who could come to my aid.

many thanks to all.

Isaac Owusu

Comment: @Owusu Isaac: try while(is.numeric(n)==F & (acr<0 ¦acr>1)).  Your orginal code would first evaluate is.numeric(n)==F & acr<0 rather than (what I believe is your intention) is.numeric(n)==F & (acr<0 ¦acr>1).

Answer (score 1):

This following example should work. Please be aware that `is.integer()`

> "does *not* test if ‘x’ contains
>   integer numbers! For that, use
>   ‘round’, as in the function
>   ‘is.wholenumber(x)’ in the examples"
>   (see `help(is.integer)`).

For that reason, I first define a new function `is.wholenumber()`.

```
is.wholenumber <- function(x, tol = .Machine$double.eps^0.5){
  abs(x - round(x)) < tol
}

n <- NULL
acr <- NULL
stay.in.loop <- TRUE

while(stay.in.loop){
  print("Please insert n and acr!") 
  n <- readline("Insert n: ")
  acr <- readline("Insert acr: ")
  n <- as.numeric(n)    
  acr <- as.numeric(acr)
  ## stay.in.loop is true IF any of the expressions is NOT TRUE 
  stay.in.loop <- !(is.wholenumber(n) & ((0 < acr) & (acr < 1)))
}
```

Comment: +1 for readline. be aware of the fact though that you'll get an error when the input is empty (when pressing enter) or a warning when entering text.

Comment: @Joris Meys: I agree that this is a very basic solution which does not check the user's input.

Answer (score 0):

NULL may be a bad initialization here, as its comparison does not give a regular boolean. Since the condition is that n should be positive, try this:

```
n   <- -2
acr <- -2
while((n<=0) | (acr<0) | (acr>1)) {
   print("enter a  positive integer and the average cancellation rate you want")
   try(n<-scan(what=integer(),nmax=1), silent=TRUE);
   try(acr<-scan(what=double(),nmax=1), silent=TRUE);
}
```

Comment: The while-loop doesn't stop when the two conditions are met.

Comment: The try should make sure that it is an integer. I will correct the condition to stop when the input is correct. We need to check n being negative to continue the loop.