# Single line user input in R

Tags: r, readline

I want to input numeric values from user in R. These numeric values will be in one line. readline() does read the values but then returns them as character making me unable to do statistical operations on those values whereas scan() doesn't take multiple numeric values in one line in R. Please help.

Sample Input

```
630 135 146 233 144 498 729 120 511 670
```

Can you suggest me a way using which I can prompt user to input these values and store them in numeric so that I can perform basic statistic operation on these values.

Comment: Why not check google first? First result http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5974967/what-is-the-correct-way-to-ask-for-user-input-in-an-r-program

Answer (score 0):

```
as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(readline()," ")))
```